# HttpErrorResponse{headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, …}

Tags: angular, http-headers, response, http-get, angular-httpclient

I am having an HttpErrorResponse with **status code:0 and message:"Http failure response** for https://api.ipify.org?format=json: 0 Unknown Error". I found this to be the case with multiple APIs I tried.

I am quite new to angular so it might be just some rookie error but i have tried alot of things for the last 7 days. And none of them works.
So please help. Any help will be appreciated.
thanks!
Here is the full error and code link

Code : [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipaddress-uml3fk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Error:

```
HttpErrorResponse{headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, …}
error: ProgressEvent
headers: HttpHeaders
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: null
<prototype>: HttpErrorResponse
```

Comment: I suspect CORS errors. Check your network tab in your console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the real answer
well...
i found it way earlier but thought i should post it here it generally means that the **host your trying to connect is not available** most of the time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

That error happended to me using Opera GX only, this browser have a AdBlocker and if its enabled sometimes generate things like this.
When I disable that tool, the problem was fix.

[image: Problem by Adblocker]

Hope I've helped